# Racket Not Loading Module File

Tags: command-line, racket

I am trying to load my racket file so that I can test it interactively similar to what DrRacket allows.

**test.rkt:**

```
#lang racket

(define blah 1)
```

I am trying to run it using this command:

`racket -it test.rkt`

Which works and I get the usual output:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.6.
>
```

But when I try to get the value of blah it doesnt work:

```
> blah
blah: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:88:7
```

How can I run this program interactively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `xrepl`: `(require xrepl)` (or add the `require` to your `.racketrc`), then use the `,enter` command to “move inside” the module:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.6.0.4.
> ,enter test.rkt
> blah
1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to reload the file after editing it without having to type all that in again?

Comment: On the off chance that this hadn't occurred to you: DrRacket, the IDE for racket, is *very very good* at doing exactly this.

Comment: @JohnClements The OP mentioned DrRacket in the question, so I’d guess they are at least aware of it, but yes, I rarely use the CLI REPL because of it. :)

Comment: @cabellicar123 Not easily, I don’t think, but you could probably script it somehow. There’s the `,require-reloadable` xrepl command, but it’s separate from `,enter`.

Comment: You don't even need to `(require xrepl)`. `,enter test.rkt` suffices.

Comment: @weberc2 Since this answer was written, Racket has changed to require xrepl by default if you have it installed.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. You just need to [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=provide#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._provide%29%29) blah so that it can be used from the repl.

```
#lang racket

(provide blah)
(define blah 1)
```

And then when you run it with `racket -it test.rkt`, you get:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.6.0.4.
> blah
1
```

Comment: This also doesn't work. It runs the file, but you can't access any symbols it defines. `; blah: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition`. `,enter test.rkt` is the right answer.